# Remove P tag from images if aligncenter class is set

Tags: the-content

I am trying to create a function that will filter the_content depending on image alignment.  So far I have this...

```
function filter_ptags_on_images($content)
{
 $content = preg_replace('/<p>\\s*?(<a .*?><img.*?><\\/a>|<img.*?>)?\\s*<\\/p>/s', '$1', $content);
    return $content;
}
```

This is removing the P tag from images but I want to modify it so that it only does this is aligncenter is set on the image.

Does anybody have an example?

Answer (score 0):

it should work like this.

```
function filter_ptags_on_images($content)
{
    $content = preg_replace('/<p>\s*?((<a.*?>)?<img[^>]+class="[^\"]*aligncenter[^\"]*".*?>(<\/a>)?)?\s*<\/p>/', '$1', $content);
    return $content;
}
```

it filters if the img tag has the class `aligncenter` and any class.

Comment: any news on this?